# Installing SSL Certificate onto a MSSQL instance

Tags: server, ssh, ssl, sql, mssql

I'm running Microsoft SQL Server 2017 on a 18.04 LTS Server (AWS Cloud). I'm looking into getting proper SSL security on the server, but I cannot seem to find any guides for Linux, only for windows. I've used Let's Encrypt in the past for my webservers, so that's not my concern. How does one go about actually installing the SSL Cert into the SQL Install? I have access to both SSH and SSMS. 
NOTE: There is NOT a webserver running, only the SQL Server.

Comment: I have run into pretty much the same problem -- sorry to see no one has answered your question. I'm going to try posting another question and if I get any answers I will link to them from here.